# $f(n+1)=f(n)\cos g(n)-g(n)\sin g(n)$ and $g(n+1)=f(n)\sin g(n)+g(n)\cos g(n)\,\,\forall n\ge 1;\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n), \lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$

Tags: limits

$f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}, g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R},f(1)=0.8,g(1)=0.6,$
$f(n+1)=f(n)\cos g(n)-g(n)\sin g(n)$ and
$g(n+1)=f(n)\sin g(n)+g(n)\cos g(n)\,\,\forall n\ge 1$
find $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n), \lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$

My working :

$(f(n+1))^2+(g(n+1))^2= (f(n))^2+(g(n))^2$
$\implies (f(n))^2+(g(n))^2=1$

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=l, \lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)=m$
$\implies l^2+m^2=1;l=l\cos m-m\sin m$ and $m=l\sin m+m\cos m$

$\implies (l^2+m^2)(1-\cos m)\sin m=0$

$\implies m=0$

$\implies l=\pm 1$

But Answer given is $l=-1,m=0$

Comment: please help in above

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Put
$$0.8=\cos(a_1), 0.6=\sin(a_1)$$

then

$$f(n+1)=\cos(g(n)+a_n)$$
$$g(n+1)=\sin(g(n)+a_n)$$

Comment: Your claim is incorrect please check $f(3)$ or $g(3)$